# Как тестировать функции, которые работают с очень большими данными?

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты

Каким образом тестируются части кода, которые возвращают или хранят очень большие объемы данных? Например, как проверить, что функция считывает данные из файла всегда в одинаковом порядке?

Пусть у нас есть некая коллекция, которая хранит какие-то данные:

```
struct collection {
  vector<int> _m_data_foo;
  vector<int> _m_data_bar;
};
```

И функция, которая считывает данные из файла:

```
collection read() {
  collection result;
  fstream input_file("C:/...");

  // Заполнение _m_data_foo
  // ...

  // Заполнение _m_data_bar
  // ...

  return result;
}
```

**Тогда как должен выглядеть тест?**

1. Так? Такой вариант мне кажется неправильным, потому что приходится в файле с тестом занимать несколько тысяч строк для проверки одного массива.

```
TEST(read, read){
  auto col = read();

  EXPECT_EQ(col._m_data_foo, vector<int>{1, 2, 3, ..., 1000000});
}
```

2. Или нужно как-то сохранить в файл результат работы функции и потом доставать это из файла и сравнивать с результатом `read`?

Answer (score 3):

Вариант 1: Если данные подчиняются некоторому закону, можно хранить в тесте процедуру генерации данных.

```
std::vector<int> gen_range(int from, int to, int step);
...
  EXPECT_EQ( col._m_data_foo, gen_range(1,1000000,1) );
```

Вариант 2: Проверить что данные починяются некоторым инвариантам.

```
  EXPECT_EQ( col._m_data_foo.size(), 1000000 );
  EXPECT_EQ( col._m_data_foo[0], 1 );
  for( size_t i=1; i<1000000; ++i )
     EXPECT_EQ( col._m_data_foo[i] ,  col._m_data_foo[i-1] + 1 );
```

Вариант 3: Если эталонные данные не упорядочены, и не могут быть проверены через инварианты - хранить эталонные данные отдельным текстом. Это не хорошо, но храните же вы данные для чтения...

```
  vector<int> ref_data{
    #include "ref_data.txt"
  };
  EXPECT_EQ(col._m_data_foo, ref_data);
```